# Get "Permission denied" in .Net Core in Linux with Process.start

Tags: linux, .net-core, debian, qemu, virsh

I've been calling virsh from my .Net Core console app in Linux using `Proccess.start` for many month but suddenly I get a permission error:

```
Permission denied
at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setUser, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean shouldThrow)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at wconfig.Menus.MAIN.Test(Object& Obj)
```

- I run my .Net Core app as root
- I can run virsh commands fine from shell
- I can run virsh commands fine with `Process.Start` if I use `bash -c MyVirshCmd...`
- I can run other commands in my .Net Core app fine, I've only seen the problem with virsh

Something strange is happening in the native .net core function `ForkAndExecProcess` and virsh.

.Net Core code example:

```
Dim PI As New ProcessStartInfo
PI.RedirectStandardOutput = False
PI.FileName = "virsh"
PI.Arguments = "list --all"
Using proc As New Process
  proc.StartInfo = PI
  proc.Start()
End Using
```

In the **/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf** config file it says `The user for QEMU processes run by the system instance.`?
I've tried to set `user` and `group` in the file to "root" but it didn't help.

In desperation I tried to restart server, didn't help of course.
I cannot think of anything that has changed on the server, it just stopped working yesterday out of the blue.
Using Debian Buster (10)
I'm lost?

Comment: Normally you should have a separate user for running qemu, most people create a user called `qemu`. Have you checked permissions, aka that root has permission to execute, all relevant executables?

Comment: But if root doesn't have the necessary rights, I assume I would see the permission error when running the command in the shell, right?

Comment: I was concerned that you where not running the command from root yourself. Though it appears you have resolved the problem, so my comment is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

YES, I got it!
By using `strace -f -o /tmp/strace.txt MyDotNetApp` I could see dotnet was executing `/root/virsh`??.
As it turns out this file existed for some reason and was 0KB!
Apparently dotnet has another path search order than the shell, so dotnet executed `/root/virsh` whereas shell executed the real virsh in `/usr/bin/virsh`. 
GOSH...this could have taking me a long time to find, well it did, but it could have taking month (scarry)!

By the was my system environment PATH is:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

So it seems dotnet uses its own "path" :-(